# Xamarin with PCLStorage - Where to place SQLite3 file?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am reading 'Xamarin in Action' by Manning Publications and working on Countr example. I am using below code to retrieve Sqlite3 file as has been mentioned in chapter 7 of book.

```
var local = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.Path;
var datafile = PortablePath.Combine(local, "counters.db3");
connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(datafile);
connection.GetConnection();
```

I wanted to add one more database which has static content that I already prepared. I need to place this database inside app's assets or resources and read it when app loads. I realized that on Windows, above code is looking for database at "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft.TestHost.x86\15.6.2\". For testing Model, ViewModel I placed the database file at that location and that helped. However, I wanted to know what is right place to put database file and how to access it so I can test in Android and iPhone emulators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, Xamarin Solution by default has multiple projects -

- App.Core that has libraries needed for designing Model and ViewModels
- App.Droid that has Android SDK libraries to build view for Android devices
- App.iOS that has iOS SDK libaries to build View for Apple devices

It is not possible to add below code in App.Core library as that project has no information about App's file system. Only App.Droid and App.iOS projects carry this information.

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine (
    Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
    "counters.db3");
```

Since we want to copy a database with pre-existing content to LocalDirectory, Setup.cs in App.Droid and App.iOS must be altered. For example, for App.Droid, below are the steps needed (This is one way and there are of course alternatives)

- Place Sqlite DB in App.Droid/Assets folder
- Create a class file (let's call it AndroidConfiguration.cs) and add a method which I call copyElementDatabaseToLocalStorage() (Code for this method can be found after these list of steps)
- In SetUp.cs, call copyElementDatabaseToLocalStorage() method

**Code for copyElementDatabaseToLocalStorage Method:**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using System.IO;
using PCLStorage;

namespace App.Droid.AndroidSpecificSetters
{
    public class AndroidConfiguration    

        public async void copyElementDatabaseToLocalStorage()
        {
            string localStorage = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.Path;
            string databaseLocation = Path.Combine(localStorage, "counters.db3");

        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(databaseLocation))
            {
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open("counters.db3")))
                {
                    using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(databaseLocation, FileMode.Create)))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                        int length = 0;
                        while ((length = binaryReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            binaryWriter.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
           ...
        }

    }

   }
}
```

**Code Inside App.Droid Setup.cs constructor**

```
    public Setup(Context applicationContext) : base(applicationContext)
    {
        AndroidConfiguration androidConfiguration = new AndroidConfiguration();
        androidConfiguration.copyElementDatabaseToLocalStorage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Environment.GetFolderPath` and store the database the location Android and IOS gives your app to store data without further permissions:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine (
        Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
        "counters.db3");
```

You can find more information on this article:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/data-and-cloud-services/data-access/part-3-using-sqlite-orm/

Comment: Thank you NicoRiff. Couple of things. 
1. I could not find Path.Combine as was mentioned in book. So had to use PortablePath.Combine. Does that achieve same result?
2. I could not find GetFolderPath or SpecialFolder under Environment Variable. Am I missing any namespace?

Comment: Or just do System.IO.Path.Combine

Comment: Should I include any namespace for Environment.GetFolderPath and Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal. IntelliSense errors when I use them "'Environment' does not contain a definition for 'GetFolderPath'", "'Environment' does not contain a definition for 'SpecialFolder'"